# OpenGL - Triangulation. Can It be used as an API?

Tags: opengl, triangulation

I need to have triangulation as a part of my project. OpenGL uses its own tessellation logic for rendering points.

Can the triangulation logic can be used as an API, giving points as input and get the triangulation index as output?

Comment: OpenGL uses just a few triangulation modes which could be easily implemented by hand and which are not anywhere good at complicated shapes or even non-convex polygons.

Comment: Are you looking for [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) by any chance? If so, that is not something OpenGL will do for you, but source for libraries which do that (such as Qhull) is freely available all over if you know what keyword to google for.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is a drawing API, not some all purpose geometry library. You must use some third party tesselation-triangulation library. FYI: GLU (gluTesselate) is *not* part of OpenGL.

> OpenGL uses its own tessellation logic for rendering points

What exactly do you mean/think by that? OpenGL takes vertex data and a primitive mode and rasters it. You may attach a tesselation shader, to refine geometry on the go, but that's not what you're probably after.